# Which encoding for ProcessBuilder parameters

Tags: java, processbuilder

Using `ProcessBuilder`, I need to be able to send non-ASCII parameters to another Java program.

In this case, a program `Abc` needs to send e.g. Arabic characters to `Def` program through the parameters. I have control of `Abc` code, but not of `Def`.

Using the normal way of `ProcessBuilder` without any playing with the encoding, it was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827546), it is not possible. `Def` recieves question marks "?????".

However, I am able to get some result, but different encodings can be used for different scenarios.

E.g. I am trying all encodings to send to the recipient, and comparing the result of what is expected.

1. Windows, IntelliJ console:

   1. Default charset: `UTF-8`
   2. Found charsets: `windows-1252`, `windows-1254` and `windows-1258`
2. Windows, command prompt:

   1. Default charset: `windows-1252`
   2. Found charsets: `CESU-8` and `UTF-8`
3. Ubuntu, command prompt:

   1. Default charset: `ISO-8859-1`
   2. Found charsets: `ISO-2022-CN`, `ISO-2022-KR`, `ISO-8859-1`, `ISO-8859-15`, `ISO-8859-9`, `x-IBM1129`, `x-ISO-2022-CN-CNS` and `x-ISO-2022-CN-GB`

My question is: how to programmatically know which correct encoding to use, since I need to have something universal?

In other words, what is the relation between the default charset and the found ones?

```
public class Abc {

  private static final Path PATH = Paths.get("."); // With maven: ./target/classes

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    var string = "hello أحمد";
    var bytes = string.getBytes();

    System.out.println("Original string: " + string);
    System.out.println("Default charset: " + Charset.defaultCharset());

    for (var c : Charset.availableCharsets().values()) {
      var newString = new String(bytes, c);

      var process = new ProcessBuilder().command("java", "-cp",
              PATH.toAbsolutePath().toString(),
              "Def", newString).start();
      process.waitFor();

      var output = asString(process.getInputStream());
      if (output.contains(string)) {
        System.out.println("Found " + c + " " + output);
      }
    }
  }

  private static String asString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    try (var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
      var builder = new StringBuilder();
      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (builder.length() != 0) {
          builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        builder.append(line);
      }
      return builder.toString();
    }
  }
}
```

```
public class Def {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(args[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: The command prompt is irrelevant. The process is being run not in a command prompt but directly from your `ProcessBuilder`, and will work with the environment variables and system variables you provide it. However, if you have control over the application you are sending to, I'd advise against passing such strings in arguments, and instead passing a JSON.

Comment: I feel you are asking how to implement your solution to your real problem, which is what? You are launching Java class `Def` and sending it Arabic characters and those characters are not displaying (or being interpreted) correctly? You can use unicode escapes instead of the actual characters, for example `\uFE81` instead of the first Arabic character in the code in your question.

Comment: You're using arabic letters but don't find it odd that an encoding for Korean language `ISO-2022-KR` "works"? Well, it only "works" by accident. You can't write code like that unless you want to end up with encoding problems and corrupted data.

Comment: Instead of launching a separate JVM, can't you just call method `main()` of class `Def` from some method in class `Abc`?

Answer (score 3):

Under the hood, what's actually being passed around is bytes, not chars. Normally, you'd expect the java method that ends up turning characters into bytes to have an overload that lets you specify charset, but, for whatever reason, it does not exist here.

How it *should* work is thusly:

- You pass a string to ProcessBuilder
- PB will turn that string into bytes using `Charset.defaultCharset()` (why? Because PB is all about making the OS do things, and the default charset reflects the OS's preferred charset).
- These bytes are then fed to the process.
- The process starts up. If it is java, and we're talking the args in `psv main(String[] args)`, the same is done in reverse: Java takes the bytes and turns them back to characters via Charset.defaultCharset(), again.

This does show an immediate issue: If the default charset is not capable of representing a certain character, then in theory you are **out of luck**.

That would strongly suggest that using java to fire up `java.exe` should ordinarily mean you can pass whatever you want (unless the characters involved aren't representable in the system's charset).

Your code is odd. In particular, this line is the problem:

> `var bytes = string.getBytes();`

This is short for `string.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset())`. So now you have your bytes in the provided charset.

> `var newString = new String(bytes, c);`

and now you're taking those bytes and turning them into a string using a completely different charset. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this. Pure gobbledygook would come out.

> In other words, what is the relation between the default charset and the found ones?

What do you mean by 'found ones'? The string "Found charsets" appears nowhere in your code. If you mean: What `Charset.availableCharsets()` returns - there is no relationship at all. availableCharsets isn't relevant for ProcessBuilder.

Comment: The answer to your updated question remains the same: Charset.defaultCharset() is it. If that is not working, either the default charset cannot represent these characters, or the app you're calling is messing it up.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to convert your String to Unicode sequences string and then pass it to another process and there convert it back to a regular String. String of Unicode sequences will always contain ASCI characters only. Here is how it may look like:

```
String encoded = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence("hello أحمد"));
```

The result will be that String encode will hold this value:

```
"\u0068\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0623\u062d\u0645\u062f"
```

This String you can safely pass to another process. In that other process, you can do the following:

```
String originalString = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(encodedString);
```

And the result will be that originalString will now hold this value:

```
"hello أحمد"
```

Class `StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder` could be found in an Open Source library called MgntUtils. You can get this library as [Maven Artifact](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils) or get it on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and JavaDoc). JavaDoc online is available [here](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html)

This library and this particular feature is used and well tested by multiple users.

**Disclamer:** This library is written by me